# Em-dash vs colon: "Remind me: what's your name again?" or "Remind me—what's your name again?"

Tags: punctuation, dashes, colons

I have a sentence (and other sentences like it) in which I'm not sure what punctuation to use.

> Remind me—what's your name again?
>   Remind me: what's your name again?

Or is there something else that would work better in sentences like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon is used to convey a proportional relationship between two parts of a sentence, eg 'Remind me **of something**. That **something** is your name.

The em dash is usually used to convey a break in thought, while connecting the utterances either side of that break.

For further info, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29#Syntactical-deductive) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_dash#Em_dash).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. The Wikipedia articles helped immensely.

Comment: As RegDwight pointed out, it is also acceptable to use a comma.

Answer (score 1):

I'd always choose a colon over a dash, unless there is some compelling need to show drama. One or the other is certainly needed in your sentence, and either will do. 
Never be tempted to use both (:--)

Answer (score 0):

I will use a simple comma, unless there's a big fat pregnant pause. It is sad to see not a single answer explore this option.

If there *is* a big fat pregnant pause, I will use an em dash ("—", not "--", it's the 21st century and proper dashes are supported everywhere).

I would not use a colon here. It can be justified, but wouldn't be my choice.

Comment: Sorry, the double hyphen is a bad habit I've adopted from using Microsoft Word. I've consistently forgotten that it doesn't actually work in other settings as an em-dash.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, I don't have the *em dash* sign on my Italian keyboard. I know there is a combination of keys which need to pressed contemporarily, and frankly one which I have never used. I tend to copy and paste the *em dash* for ease and speed (not very efficient, I know but always easier than looking up the combination of keys). Is there an idiot-proof way of typing this symbol without resorting to have it written on a piece of paper, which I'll end up losing or forgetting where I put in any case?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry if you get this twice. I have to admit that I'm not all that clear on how international keyboards work, but hopefully [this will be able to help you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes).

On a Mac, an em-dash character is accomplished by pressing `Opt, Shift, -` (minus). On Windows, hold the `Alt` key and press `0151` on your right keypad, in that order. If you have a laptop, you may have to use a special tool.

On Windows, this tool is called the "Character Map". On Linux, [you may want to read this](http://fsymbols.com/character-maps/linux/).

Comment: @Abluescarab  The key combo doesn't work, it just pastes the last thing I copied. I have a laptop, Windows... yes... I know. It's Vista. Do you see? Too much hassle and I have to look for a special tool on control panel, I guess. Ack! Thank you for your patience and help, at least I hope RegDwight will speak less disparagingly of those who do not have the em dash punctuation mark at their fingertips and make do with a double hyphen. I will look at the wiki link later but I suspect I have already seen it, yonder ago. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry that it didn't help. I know I have a hard time remembering key combinations like `Alt+0151`. The only one I remember is the copyright symbol.

Comment: @RegDwi, The question is left unanswered: What's the diff then between colon vs emdash

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use any punctuation. **Remind me what's your name again?** would be fine.

Comment: I disagree. Perhaps you mean, 'Remind me what your name is again.'?

Comment: @Leon I'm confused. Could you break the sentence down into subject, predicate and object and highlight the mistake I made? I know it's too much to ask for but it'll be really helpful.

Comment: your name - your name is x - what your name is is x - these are all declarative forms. 'What is your name' is an interrogative form. Your suggestion put an interrogative sentence within an imperative sentence, which needed a punctuation mark to highlight the change in intention. Mine made a declarative clause the object of an imperative sentence, and as such, would not have needed a punctuation mark. Hope this helps. :)